# Describing the ordinary irreducible characters of a special $p$-group $p^{n+m}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $P$ be a special $p$-group $p^{n+m}$. So $P$ will  have $p^m$ linear characters. How does one **describe (or determine) the other  ordinary irreducible characters of $P$**  and will they **all be faithful?** How many **ordinary irreducible characters** will **$P$ have in total**. Also, what can we say about the **orders of elements in the conjugacy classes** of $P$? I am familiar with the case when $P=p^{1+2k}$ is an extra-special $p$-group, then $P$ will have  $p^{2k}$ linear characters and $p-1$ faithful ordinary characters of degree $p^k$.

Comment: If $n>1$ then there cannot be any faithful irreducible (complex) representations because the centre is not cyclic.

Comment: Also I don't think the character degrees are a fixed function of $p$, $n$ and $m$. In the case $3^{2+4}$, in some examples there are $36$ of degree $3$ and $4$ of degree $9$, and in others there are $8$ of degree $9$.

Comment: One interesting case occurs when $P$ admits a group of automorphisms which acts irreducibly on $P/Z(P)$ but trivially on $Z(P)$. Then for every maximal subgroup $M$ of $Z(P)$, $P/M$ is extraspecial (exercise). It follows that every nonlinear ordinary irreducible character of $P$ has degree $p^{m/2}$.